# Gmail home page css

Tags: html, css

I'm more of a programmer than a web designer, I am trying to do a simple (I think) design like the home page of gmail https://mail.google.com/intl/fr/mail/help/about.html

I have a div in the center of my screen with a `overflow:hidden` so the background image don't resize.

In that div, I have 2 other div, one at the left and one at the right, the probleme is, since the main div is `overflow:hidden` when i shrink the page the right div is not visible anymore.

You can see a demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/e7MMQ/

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: it is visible...you have to scroll

Comment: How can i make the right div to not got out of the screen when i shrink the page ? Since the parent div is overflow:hidden and have a fixed width

Answer (score 0):

first of all the background has nothing to do with div overflow , you could just use

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```

and for you divs

just use `float : left;` and `float : right ;`

if this what you are trying to do :

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/e7MMQ/1/

it is because you have specified a width , and your div is still there but you to scroll to right to see it.

Comment: But if I don't specify the width, my image will be distorted

Comment: then just use : background-size:100% auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;  http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/e7MMQ/2/

Comment: if you dont want your image distorted you have two options , either to accept teh fact it will get cropped upon resizing window, or to keep one aspect fixed ; height or width.

Comment: Well i am trying to keep the height of the picture and when the page become smaller on the width size, instead of resize the picture, just cut it (show less on width) same as https://mail.google.com/intl/fr/mail/help/about.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try applying overflow:hidden in your left/right divs and make them fixed. Thats assuming you dont have any content inside the larger container and everything is in the left/right div.

Then make your larger container a fixed size that is the combined size of your left/right divs.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="left">Some content</div>
<div id="right">Some other content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
width:300px;
height:300px;
}
#left{
float:left;
width:150px;
height:300px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#right{
float:right;
width:150px;
height:300px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Hope that helps!